# Migrating reports from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2014 and SSAS 2005 cube to SSAS 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssas

As SQL Server 2005 end of life is getting closer I'm facing inevitable job of migrating databases, SSIS packages, SSRS reports and SSAS cubes. Since newest version of SQL Server is SQL Server 2014 we are probably need to switch to it.
I have read few texts on  migrating from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014 but i have not found anything about migrating from SQL Server 2005.

Have somebody else done something similar and can it be done in first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to your question, since it will totally depend on the complexity of SSIS packages, SSRS reports and SSAS Cubes.

Doing [in-place upgrade](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29330/8783) is always risky, since if something goes wrong, it would be difficult to rollback. A side-by-side migration is always a good and reliable method, since if something goes wrong, you already have a system up and running that you can point to.

Always, test, test and test your migration and have a fully tested rollback plan. Use [**upgrade advisor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256(v=sql.120).aspx) *(this touches DB Engine, SSIS, SSRS and SSAS)* and fully address all the issues raised by it.

- I have written a thorough answer for [database migration and post restore steps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783)
- For SSRS migration, I have [written it here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68161/8783).
- Devin Knight talks about [Upgrading Packages to SSIS 2012](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2012/05/16/upgrading-packages-to-ssis-2012/) and msdn has a whitepaper on [5 Tips for a Smooth SSIS Upgrade to SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667275.aspx)
- For SSAS, [this method](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2010/03/31/migrating-a-cube-in-sql-server-analysis-services-2005-to-sql-server-analysis-services-2008.aspx) should work in your case as well.